# Динамическая отрисовка элементов внутри динамически созданной панели c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно в каждой панели которые созданы динамически с именами типа "panel_1_1" нарисовать несколько pictureBox. Как это сделать? То есть как обратится к панели которой еще нет, но её имя заранее известно?

Мой набросок, тут как пример пытался вывести хотяб в одну панель, а дальше это дело в цикл. Но ничего не выводит:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
            {
                Panel tempPanel = new Panel();
                tempPanel.Name = "panel_" + (2).ToString() + "_" + 9.ToString();
                tempPanel.Controls.Add(new Panel()
                {
                    Name = "pictureBox_" + (j + 1).ToString() + "_" + i.ToString(),
                    Location = new Point(12 + i * 50, j * 50),
                    Size = new Size(50, 50),
                    BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ball,
                    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                    BackColor = Color.Transparent
                });

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Controls["panel_" + 2.ToString() + "_" + 9.ToString()].Controls.Add(new PictureBox(){
//...
});
```